# Excel or VBA: If a match exists in column, how do I add one to text string sequentially

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to take the first 3 letters of a name and add three digits after it, using "LEFT(B6,3)&100", so starting with 100 then adding +1 in sequential order. So, I want the cell in Column B to check for a match of AAA100, and if this exists, it will loop til no match exists, so AAA101, then AAA102, etc. Tried functions, but can't seem to make it work and am wondering if this would be easier to program in VBA

Comment: can you please share some sample data with expected results? If you want a solution using `vba`, people here are expecting you to share you own code first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in multiple columns:

```
C6 = LEFT(B6,3)
D6 = C6 & 100 + COUNTIFS(B$2:B6, C6) - 1
```

What this is doing is counting how many times "AAA" appears between row 2 and the current row, and adds 100 to it.

This may not be appropriate if you're spreadsheet is really large because COUNTIFS won't be that efficient, but it does avoid using VBA